# How to convert datetime.datetime tzinfo to proper datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime, tzinfo

I have a variable as -

```
present_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 26, 13, 11, 35, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Expected output -

```
2022-09-26T13:11:35Z
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `present_date.isoformat(timespec="seconds").replace("+00:00", "Z")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isoformat` method to convert the datetime object to [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) format. i.e. your expected output format.

You can do the operation as follows:

```py
present_date.isoformat('T')
```

Above code will give you output: `2022-09-26T13:11:35+00:00`. This output is of type `str`.

The catch here is that as you mentioned you need `Z` in your expected output, so as per [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) format, Z is just a constant written for your timezone. i.e. the part after `+` sign in output. So you can just replace `+00:00` with `Z` by using string operation.

The Final expression if you want `Z` in your output would be:

```py
present_date.isoformat('T').replace("+00:00", "Z")
```

Above code will produce output: `2022-09-26T13:11:35Z`

Comment: Please note that, we haven't used `astimezone()` method because you have already provided timezone while creating datetime object. If there is no timezone specified while creating datetime object then we need to use `astimezone` method before using `isoformat` method. i.e. `present_date.astimezone().isoformat('T').replace("+00:00", "Z")`

Comment: No this is not chatgpt. can you explain why this won't work with fractional seconds? afak unless we don't specify `timespec` explicitely, `isoformat` does return the complete string along with microseconds if exists. It's default behaviour just as you said string separator `T` is default.

Comment: give it a try: `datetime.now().isoformat()` - it's the other way around, if you have non-zero microseconds, you *have* to set the timespec to get e.g. seconds precision